# How to simplify array filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, vue.js, arrow-functions

I want to know how to simplify this in order to avoid duplicating the lower case and includes condition for each property.

```
 items() {
  return this.table.filter.keyword
    ? this.dataArray.filter(
        item =>
          item.nombre.toLowerCase().includes(this.table.filter.keyword) ||
          item.paisOrigen
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(this.table.filter.keyword) ||
          item.ciudad.toLowerCase().includes(this.table.filter.keyword) ||
          item.sector.toLowerCase().includes(this.table.filter.keyword) ||
          item.contratadorPor
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(this.table.filter.keyword) ||
          item.moneda.toLowerCase().includes(this.table.filter.keyword)
      )
    : this.dataArray;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because question about optimizing working code are more on topic for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can have a function which contains this functionality and call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really want to lower the repetition you could do something like this.

```
 items() {
  const lowerIncludes = (val) => val.toLowerCase().includes(this.table.filter.keyword)
  const fields = ['nombre', 'paisOrigen', 'ciudad', 'sector', 'contratadorPor', 'moneda']
  return this.table.filter.keyword ? this.dataArray.filter(item => fields.some(f => lowerIncludes(item[f]))) : this.dataArray
 }
```

you make the `.toLowerCase().includes(this.table.filter.keyword)` into it's own function. then you list the fields you want to include in the `or` filter you're using.

You then take `fields.some(f => lowerIncludes(item[f])` to work like all of your `||` statements. If the keyword is in any of the fields, it will return true.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the map function before applying the filter:

1. Use map to convert values to lowercase (you can use for...in loop to
   transform all properties)
2. Apply filter on the result of the map.

```js
this.data.map(item => {
  let ret = {};
  for (let p in item) {
    ret[p] = item[p].toLowerCase();
  }
  return ret;
}).filter(item => {
  //... perform your filter logic here...
});
```